# Pandas Add New Column using Lookup using Multiple Columns from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
    'pp':[3,'',2,'',1,0,4, 3, 2, 1, '', 0], 
    'pc':[6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1]
})

|    |   id | pp   |   pc |
|---:|-----:|:-----|-----:|
|  0 |    1 | 3    |    6 |
|  1 |    1 |      |    5 |
|  2 |    1 | 2    |    4 |
|  3 |    1 |      |    3 |
|  4 |    1 | 1    |    2 |
|  5 |    1 | 0    |    1 |
|  6 |    2 | 4    |    6 |
|  7 |    2 | 3    |    5 |
|  8 |    2 | 2    |    4 |
|  9 |    2 | 1    |    3 |
| 10 |    2 |      |    2 |
| 11 |    2 | 0    |    1 |


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 
    'pp':['', 3, 4, 1, 2, ''], 
    'yu':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
})

|    |   id | pp   |   yu |
|---:|-----:|:-----|-----:|
|  0 |    1 |      |    1 |
|  1 |    1 | 3    |    2 |
|  2 |    1 | 4    |    3 |
|  3 |    2 | 1    |    4 |
|  4 |    2 | 2    |    5 |
|  5 |    2 |      |    6 |
```

I'd like to merge the two so that final results look like this.

```
|    |   id | pp   | pc   |   yu |
|---:|-----:|:-----|:-----|-----:|
|  0 |    1 |      |      |    1 |
|  1 |    1 | 0    | 1    |    2 |
|  2 |    1 | 3    | 6    |    3 |
|  3 |    2 | 1    | 3    |    4 |
|  4 |    2 | 2    | 4    |    5 |
|  5 |    2 |      |      |    6 |
```

Basically, the df1 has the value that I need to lookup from.
df2 is the has `id` and `pp` column that are used to lookup.
However when I do
`pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['id', 'pp'], how='left')` results in

```
|    |   id | pp   |   pc |   yu |
|---:|-----:|:-----|-----:|-----:|
|  0 |    1 |      |    5 |    1 |
|  1 |    1 |      |    3 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 | 3    |    6 |    2 |
|  3 |    1 | 4    |  nan |    3 |
|  4 |    2 | 1    |    3 |    4 |
|  5 |    2 | 2    |    4 |    5 |
|  6 |    2 |      |    2 |    6 |
```

This is not correct because it looks at empty rows as well.
If the value in df2 is empty, there should be no mapping.

I do want to keep the empty rows in df2 as it showed so can't use `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

We can `dropna` for empty row in `df1`

```
out = pd.merge(df2, df1.replace({'':np.nan}).dropna(), on=['id', 'pp'], how='left')
Out[121]: 
   id pp  yu   pc
0   1      1  NaN
1   1  3   2  6.0
2   1  4   3  NaN
3   2  1   4  3.0
4   2  2   5  4.0
5   2      6  NaN
```